# Highlighting only 1 cell above and 1 cell below the relative value

Tags: excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I want to highlight only 2 cells, 1 above and 1 below, closest to the relative value.

For example, my relative value is cell A5, I want A2 and A4 to be highlighted.

```
   A
1  7
2  6
3 -2
4  1
5  5
```

I tried conditional formatting `=ISNUMBER(MATCH(ABS(A$5-A1),SMALL(ABS(A$5-A$1:A$4),ROW($1:$2)),0))`. However, it highlights 2 cells that are closest to the relative value, regardless of direction/magnitude. In this case, A1 and A2 were highlighted.

Comment: What is highlighting? Is / can  the "relative value" or its range be stored in a cell or variable? To clear the terminology, do you want to **select** the cells or **fill/shade** the cells with a background color?

Comment: @ashleedawg By that I meant if the cells meet the condition, they will be highlighted through conditional formatting. It actually doesn't have to be highlighting, it could just become bold or italic. I could just manually select the cells, but I have many columns and my relative values vary on row 5, e.g., B5, C5, D5, etc.

Comment: Always row 5? Every column? It would make more sense to see a sample of your data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next smallest:

```
=(A1=LARGE(IF($A$1:$A$5<A$5,$A$1:$A$5),1))
```

Next largest:

```
=(A1=SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$5>A$5,$A$1:$A$5),1))
```

However if there's a tie then all matches would be highlighted.